# Edit Database in PHP-Site

Tags: php, database, mysqli, edit

I'm very new to php and databases. So I need you to help me out please.
I want to edit the data of my database online in my php site. But the form is empty and I don't know why.
I don't know if you need more information so this is the code of the table with the form. If you need more let me know.

```
<table>
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","y","z","xyz");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
mysqli_close($con);
?>

  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Firma</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" 
    size="40" value="<? echo "$row[Name]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wer</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="wer" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Wer]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Erhalten</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="erhalten" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Erhalten]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Digital</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="digital" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Digital]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Betrag in Euro</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="betrag" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Betrag]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bezahlt am</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="bezahlt" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Bezahlt]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anmerkung</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="anmerkung" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Anmerkung]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your `while` loop has no body which probably will generate a syntax error. Check your server logs.

Comment: use mysqli_close($con); at the end of </table> tag

Comment: i don't know if I even Need this Loop! Do I Need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code**

1)If data base contain more rows it shows multiple form

2)You need to show one form you need to restrict in query using **where** class

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","y","z","xyz");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
  <table>
  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Firma</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" 
    size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wer</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="wer" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo $row['Wer']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Erhalten</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="erhalten" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo $row['Erhalten']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Digital</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="digital" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo $row['Digital']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Betrag in Euro</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="betrag" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo $row['Betrag']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bezahlt am</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="bezahlt" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo "$row[Bezahlt]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anmerkung</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="anmerkung" size="40" 
      value="<?php echo $row['Anmerkung'];?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
<?php } ?>
```

**Edit:**
change query like below

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente where id={$_REQUEST['id']}");
```

Comment: so i should use "where" instead of "while"? or what do you mean? now i have a form for each row as you said!

Comment: so far so good! if i paste it as you wrote it works for id=1 but if i want it to work with the id which is in the adress-bar (for example:edit_form.php?id=10) it won't work if i write the line as: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente where id='$id'"); whats wrong there?

Comment: see above edit but you need to learn basic php first buddy.. Refer:http://www.php.net

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","y","z","xyz");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

?>

  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Firma</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" 
    size="40" value="<? echo "$row[Name]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wer</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="wer" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Wer]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Erhalten</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="erhalten" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Erhalten]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Digital</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="digital" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Digital]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Betrag in Euro</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="betrag" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Betrag]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bezahlt am</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="bezahlt" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Bezahlt]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anmerkung</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="anmerkung" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[Anmerkung]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>

<?php mysqli_close($con);?>
```

// close connection at the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the while loop.Try this it will show you the values in the form

```
<table>
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","y","z","xyz");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Transparente");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
mysqli_close($con);
?>



    <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
      <input type="text" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">
        <tr>        
          <td>Firma</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" 
        size="40" value="<? echo "$row[Name]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Wer</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="wer" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Wer]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Erhalten</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="erhalten" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Erhalten]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Digital</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="digital" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Digital]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Betrag in Euro</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="betrag" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Betrag]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bezahlt am</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="bezahlt" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Bezahlt]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Anmerkung</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="anmerkung" size="40" 
          value="<? echo "$row[Anmerkung]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" 
          name="submit value" value="Edit">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
<?php }?>
```